# CSS: Div won't position

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of my problem:

[Screenshot of rendered page http://cl.ly/image/0E2N1W1m420V/Image%202012-07-22%20at%203.25.44%20PM.png](http://cl.ly/image/0E2N1W1m420V/Image%202012-07-22%20at%203.25.44%20PM.png)

My first error is that there's a ton of empty space between the banner and the "Web Design" `div`.
My second error is that the "Web Development" `div` should be beside the "Web Design" `div`. The widths of these `div`s are both specified as 23% and I've tried using the `float` property but that didn't work either.

HTML:

```html
<div id="maininfo">
    <div id="eyediv">
        <li><a class="eye"></a></li>
        <h1>Web Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia condimentum dignissim. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc in metus id lorem accumsan vehicula. Proin posuere lacus id odio tincidunt mattis sit amet et sapien. Nulla facilisi. Quisque sodales risus eget mauris adipiscing vitae scelerisque metus mattis. Praesent lectus purus, feugiat eleifend faucibus nec, volutpat sed eros. Praesent quis ante pharetra mauris pretium porttitor.</p>
        <button type="button">SEE MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div id="spannerdiv">
        <li><a class="spanner"></a></li>
        <h1>Web Development</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lacinia condimentum dignissim. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc in metus id lorem accumsan vehicula. Proin posuere lacus id odio tincidunt mattis sit amet et sapien. Nulla facilisi. Quisque sodales risus eget mauris adipiscing vitae scelerisque metus mattis. Praesent lectus purus, feugiat eleifend faucibus nec, volutpat sed eros. Praesent quis ante pharetra mauris pretium porttitor.</p>
        <button type="button">SEE MORE</button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#maininfo {
    clear: both;
}

#maininfo li {
    list-style: none;
}

#eyediv {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 23%;
}

#spannerdiv {
    width: 23%;
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the HTML as text rather than as an image? (Observe the code formatting button if you don't know how to format it correctly.)

Comment: `clear: both` forces the `div` to have the line to itself, you should remove that.

Comment: @DavidThomas Just what I was going to say, but was debating between a comment and an answer. Maybe you should post that up as an answer?

Comment: Changed from images to text. :)

I removed the clear: both and my problem wasn't fixed. :(

Comment: And can we have the HTML as text; it makes it so much easier to help create relevant demos.

Comment: @TomDwyer To address your comment in David's answer, can you post both the HTML and CSS for the entire page. That way we can have a more accurate idea of what is happening on your page - the problem could be in the blue banner, the two divs you were trying to position or the container div for them.

Comment: I would like to point out that the use of the `li` element in this instance, does not comply with web standards, and that you should ensure that you don't get into such a habit.

Comment: Regarding your second question as to why there's a huge gap between the banner and the other divs: Do you have the HTML/CSS that makes up the banner section? Also, if the current HTML you posted is accurate, you're missing a closing tag for <div id="maininfo">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As originally mentioned in my comment, the `clear: both` forces the element to have that 'line' of the display to itself, preventing other floated elements from aligning with it. Removing that declaration should allow the floating to resume as you wish.

Also you should `float` the elements in order that they can appear together.

Comment: To expand on this, please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYJfe/1/) for an example of what effect using `float` will have.

Comment: Wow thank you Saladin! Now just to figure why there is a HUGE gap between the blue and the div... nothing shows on firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `clear: both;` and apply `float: left;`

Comment: Took this advice and this is the result: http://cl.ly/image/1F380p0n3m1i/Image%202012-07-22%20at%203.57.28%20PM.png

With the following code:
#maininfo li{
 list-style: none;
}

#eyediv{
 margin-left: 15%;
 width: 23%;
}

#spannerdiv{
 width: 23%;
 padding-left: 3px;
 float: left;
}

Answer (score 0):

The `clear:both;` apply to the parent div **maininfo** and not to child divs, so that should not be a problem. This should only make the ***maininfo*** div have the line to itself.

The `float` on **spannerdiv** will make only *it* to float and won't neccesary be placed next to the **eyediv**, as it float up to the first parent div which has `position: relative`.

I'd suggest doing something else in order to line the two divs next to each other. Wrap the divs you want aligned (in this case eyediv and spannerdiv) in a parent div and with CSS give the child divs `display:inline-block;`. And you'd also want to align them vertically.
Something like:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapperdiv">
    <div id="eyediv">
        <li><a class="eye"></a></li>
        <h1>Web Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
        <button type="button">SEE MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div id="spannerdiv">
        <li><a class="spanner"></a></li>
        <h1>Web Development</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum do...</p>
        <button type="button">SEE MORE</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#eyediv {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 23%;
}

#spannerdiv {
    width: 23%;
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: left;
}

#eyediv, #spannerdiv {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Now all you need is to position the parent div wherever you need.

Hope it helps